# Hide or Remove duplicate options in dropdownlist

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I'm using `WebForms`. In my Form, I have a `dropdownlist` control. Sometimes the `Select` option gets added twice in my from. How can remove this duplicate option or hide it?

I've tried to count how many times `Select` option is added then hide it but wasn't successful.

The reason why it's adding it twice is because `grdview_Color_DataBound` gets called twice.

[image]

```
    <select name="ctl00$MainContent$grdview_Color$ctl10$ddl_Grd_Color" id="MainContent_grd_ddl_grdview_Color" class="form-control dropdown">
       <option value="0" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select</option>
       <option value="0" disabled="disabled">Select</option>
       <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
       <option value="Red">Red</option>
       <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
       <option value="Green">Green</option>
    </select>


    protected void grdview_Color_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListItem firstItem = new ListItem("Select", "0");
        firstItem.Attributes.Add("disabled", "disabled");
        ddl.DataSource = dataSource;
        ddl.DataTextField = TextField;
        ddl.DataValueField = ValueField;
        ddl.DataBind();
        ddl.Items.Insert(0, firstItem);
    }
```

Comment: You are trying to fix the symptom rather than the problem. You should figure out how the extra options are getting into the list.

Comment: You need to show your markup and where you are using this code.

Comment: maybe clear ddl before data bind it?

Comment: This is not the original markup - this is the generated markup. Check your aspx or ascx files, whichever you are using.

Comment: I checked the Javascript code and found out that there was a code that was appending the Select option and disabling it. Thank you guys for helping :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the [AppendDataBoundItems](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.appenddatabounditems.aspx) property to true to preserve the existing values in the DDL. You also need to ensure that you are not doing it on every postback - your code sample does not show if and how you are doing this in the Page_Load() method.

Comment: I'll look into AppendDataBoundItems. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

A naive way would be to store the items in the drop down list in some kind of container like a list. Clear the drop down items and then loop through your container, only adding unique items back to the drop down items list with something like:

```
// Save the items
savedItems = dropDownItems.Items;

// Clear The items
dropDownItems.Items.Clear();

// Go through the container adding unique items to the drop down list
foreach (string item in savedItems){
    if (!dropDownItems.Items.Contains(item)) {
        dropDownItems.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

of course this way is not the best way, but it is a way if you are in a hurry.